# Get last Android System shutdown time from API

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.3, android-event, android-developer-api

Is there a way to get the last Shutdown time using Android API or any Android log?

I know I can use `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` event with a `BroadcastReceviver` to store the date of the shutdown, but I just want the time when the last shutdown occurred and I want to treat this event when the phone starts.

Does the API provide this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Write ACTION_SHUTDOWN and BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver

In ACTION_SHUTDOWN broadcast receiver you can save the current time to shared preference like this

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("LastShutDown", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor et = sp.edit();
et.putString("LastShutDownTime", currentTimeValue);
et.commit();
```

In BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver(it will call when device starts or boot up) you can read last shutdown time from SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("LastShutDown", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String lastShutDownTime=sp.getString("LastShutDownTime",null);
```